# How to "include" libvlc and sdl1.2 on Raspbian C++ project?

Tags: c++, linux, raspbian, libvlc, sdl-1.2

I have installed "libsdl1.2-dev" and "libvlc" (with sudo apt-get install blah) in Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi, I'm using gcc to compile the example project from https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_SDL/

This is my compile command:

```
gcc -fpermissive test.cpp -lvlc -lsdl1.2-dev -o test
```

It seems to compile (after I added -fpermissive and manually placed the vlc headers in usr/include/vlc)  the error seems to happen during the linking phase, I get these 2 errors;

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvlc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdl1.2-dev
```

I'm a bit new to Linux and I can't work out why it can't find them. I'm also unsure where it installs them by default, there seem to be a few different places they could be.

Comment: Libraries are usually installed in "/usr/lib" directory, check if libvlc.so lists when you enter "$ ls -al | grep vlc" in terminal. If your library is present in a different path you need to include the library path by using the command "$export PATH=PATH:<your_library_path>"

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually place headers in /usr/include. If that's necessary, something is wrong. Which headers did you need to copy?

Comment: @AkshayVernekar Nothing lists when I type that command.  And a manual inspection of /usr/lib doesn't seem to have any libvlc file or even vlc file or folder.

However, when I run "sudo apt-get install vlc" I get "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."  Perhaps Raspbian likes to put libraries in a different folder?  How can I find out?

Comment: @JuliusBullinger Yes it didn't seem right to have to do that.  But I was trying to be a "good programmer" and first try to solve everything myself ;)  I copied the full "header" folder to "/usr/include/vlc"  This included 14 files such as libvlc.h, libvlc_dialog.h etc. and a plugins folder.  This solved an error with gcc not being able to find "vlc/vlc.h" and got me to where I am now; linker errors.

Comment: @Domarius, that's fine, you'll know the next time. :) General hint: You shouldn't ever have to move files around that have been installed by a package. If your build doesn't find the files, you need to it them where to find them. Although I admit it's really strange that it couldn't find them, because ``#include<vlc/libvlc.h>`` *should just work* if the files are in /usr/include/vlc. Can you run ``echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -`` and ``gcc -print-search-dirs`` and paste the output?

Comment: @JuliusBullinger thanks for help! The answer from "Nikos C." pointed out I should have installed "libvlc-dev", not just "vlc", and he got the thing finally compiling by way of including the pkg-config command :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pkg-config to get the needed compile and link flags. `pkg-config --cflags sdl libvlc` will print the needed compilation flags, and `pkg-config --libs sdl libvlc` the needed link flags. You can use the `$()` feature of the shell to embed the output of pkg-config directly into your compile command. Also, use `g++` to compile and link C++ code. `gcc` is for C code.

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags sdl libvlc) -fpermissive test.cpp -o test $(pkg-config --libs sdl libvlc)
```

The package names `sdl` and `libvlc` correspond to `*.pc` files that are installed in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`. If no such files exist, then that means you forgot to install the `-dev` versions of the sdl and vlc libraries. So check if there's a `libvlc-dev` package you need to install. Use this:

```
apt-cache search vlc | grep dev
```

See if there's a dev package for libvlc that you need.

Comment: You covered everything and I got it working. Yes I was missing the -dev version of vlc, and it stopped complaining about missing -lvlc. But also even though I had installed libsld1.2-dev, it still complained about missing -lsdl1.2-dev, or -lsdl1.2 or even -lsdl, I tried all of those variations.  But using the command above (by including pkg-config in my compile command) the program actually compiled and ran successfully!

And the pkg-config --libs command reveals the mysterious linker name of sdl is -lSDL - capitalised! I never would have guessed it.

Answer (score 1):

To install libraries and header files, try `sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev` this should install all the dependent libraries in the correct library paths. `sudo apt-get install vlc` is used to install the application which in your case you dont need.

Comment: Thank you, that was the case.  And the answer from "Nikos C." got the thing finally compiling by way of including the pkg-config command :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install vlc`, you're probably missing some plugins and stuff

Comment: Yes I've done that previously, and it always returns with "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded." because libvlc is already included in this version of Raspbian.

Comment: `libvlc` does not equal `vlc` in terms of packaging (at least for ubuntu)

Comment: You were right, I definitely didn't realise that. That solved the missing -lvlc problem, and the answer from "Nikos C." got the thing finally compiling by way of including the pkg-config command :)